# layout file is not loading in magento custom module

Tags: magento, layout, block, magento-1.9

I am trying to load template file from layout in my module but my layout xml file is not adding in config.xml .I tried number of solution but I don't know what mistake I am doing.Please help me and tell me where I am wrong.I added my code below..

IndexController.php

```
    <?php
class Magemodul_Test_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
     public function indexAction()
     {
          $this->loadLayout();
          $this->renderLayout();
     }
}
?>
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
         <modules>
            <Magemodul_Test>
              <version>1.0.0</version>
            </Magemodul_Test>
         </modules>
         <frontend>
           <routers>
              <magemodultest>
                  <use>standard</use>
                  <args>
                     <module>Magemodul_Test</module>
                     <frontName>test</frontName>
                  </args>
               </magemodultest>
           </routers>
           <layout>
              <updates>
                <magemodultest>
                  <file>test.xml</file>
                </magemodultest>
              </updates>
            </layout>
        </frontend>
        <global>
             <blocks>
                 <test>
                      <class>Magemodul_Test_Block</class>
                 </test>
              </blocks>
        </global>
    </config>
```

block file Monblock.php

```
<?php
class Magemodul_Test_Block_Monblock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
     public function methodblock()
     {      
         return 'informations about my block !!' ;
     }
}
```

layout xml file test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
      <test_index_index>
           <reference name="content">
                <block type="test/monblock"  name="afficher_monbloc" template="test/afficher.phtml">
           </reference>
      </test_index_index>
</layout>
```

template file afficher.phtml

```
<?php
    echo $this->getmethodblock();
?>
```

Comment: Your method name is methodblock() and you are calling getmethodblock() .

Comment: I corrected it. My text.xml file is not adding in config.xml . layout file if not executing.how can i check it.